# Left Join in Django Model Multi-table Inheritance in Admin app

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Scenario:

Let's say I want to extend Django's `User` model using multi-table inheritance. Let's say the model I created for that is called `CustomUser`.

Now let's assume that there are already existing records in the database corresponding to the `User` model and the table corresponding to the `CustomUser` model is still empty.

Now I want CustomUser model to be accessible from the Django's Admin app. What I noticed is only User model records which has a corresponding record in the CustomUser table is included in the **change list** of CustomUser, as if an INNER JOIN is being done behind the scene in the query... (I checked using `connection.queries` and it was indeed an INNER JOIN).

Now I want to change this behaviour so that a LEFT JOIN is done to retrieve records pertaining to CustomerUser.

How can I achieve this in Django?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you define the `CustomUser` model and use it in the Django Admin?

Comment: I defined the CustomUser model using the multi-table inheritance as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance, and displayed it in the Django Admin the usual way i.e. registered it inside a file named admin.py.. Did not customize it though...

Comment: Maybe what I really want to do is to make those additional fields I defined in the CustomUser model to be accessible from the User model page in the Admin Page. How can I make the User model (or maybe the admin page) aware of those additional fields defined in CustomUser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below in any working admin.py.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
#### below imports your custom user model
from accounts.models import CustomUser   

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CustomUser   

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Above will show your `CustomUser` model in User in admin. now you can access User fields from UserProfileAdmin by `User__first_name` etc. pardon for bad english.

Comment: almost, but not really solved the problem. What is happening is, since CustomUser inherited from User (multi-table inheritance), CustomUser is treated as a separate object which also contains all the attributes it inherited from User. Therefore, those inherited fields were repeatedly shown in the inline view pertaining to the CustomUser...

Comment: this approach works if I define a one-to-one relationship instead of using a multi-table relationship between the two models... thanks!

Comment: technically, they have a one-to-one relationship between them, as described in the implementation of the multi-table inheritance.

Comment: using `exclude` try to exclude those fields.